# How to get r.KeyPress to recognize double letters?

Tags: java, keypress, keyevent

I am trying to write a fairly simple script to simulate keypresses repeatedly. KeyPress works, but for some reason, it won't recognize double letters, nor will it allow a loop, be it do-while, if-then, or for loops. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class robot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
    }

}
```

The output is always `HAPY BIRTHDAY`. The loops always cause fatal errors with syntax. Any help with either problem is appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to call `keyRelease(...)` after each `keyPress(...)` as well? Otherwise the key just stays down.

Comment: Yes thank you, that was the key detail I'd forgotten. (pun intended)